# Frequency of spring and pulley system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, spring, vibrations

I need some help with this problem.

[image]

I have to find the natural frequency of this system, the problem says that the cylinder has a mass of $m$, spring constant is $k$ and the string to the right is inextensible.

I am currently trying using the energy method but apparently my answer is wrong, I came up with the following:

Kinetic energy of cylinder = $\frac{1}{2} \cdot  \frac{1}{2} m r^{2} \ddot{\theta ^{2}}$

Potential energy of spring = $\frac{1}{2}  k r^{2} \theta ^{2}$

With these equations I came up with a natural frequency of $\omega = \sqrt{\frac{2k}{m}}$ but apparently the answer is $\omega = \sqrt{\frac{8k}{3m}}$.

Wondering if anyone could help me, thanks.

Comment: Why do you have two dots in the kinetic energy?

Answer (score 1):

First, as G. Smith, mentioned, the kinetic energy term should have $\dot{\theta}^2$ instead of $\ddot{\theta}^2$. I'm assuming that's a typo.

Your mistake here is in your choice of pivot. The problem statement claims that "the string to the right is inextensible." That means that the pivot should be chosen as the point on the right where the string attaches to the cylinder.

Writing down the energies with that assumption yields the correct answer.